# reference part of a variable's name by another variable's value

Tags: php, variables

i am running a loop through a multidimensional array that looks like this:

```
     $runcount = 0;

     while ($runcount <= 90){
            if ($RankingsArray[0][$runcount] == "Rank" or
                $RankingsArray[0][$runcount] == "Positional" or
                $RankingsArray[0][$runcount] == "Adjusted" or
                $RankingsArray[0][$runcount] == "Name" or
                $RankingsArray[0][$runcount] == "Team" or
                $RankingsArray[0][$runcount] == "Bye" or
                $RankingsArray[0][$runcount] == "ADP" or
                $RankingsArray[0][$runcount] == "ADP Diff" or
                $RankingsArray[0][$runcount] == "ADV" or
                $RankingsArray[0][$runcount] == "ADV Diff" or
                $RankingsArray[0][$runcount] == "Games" or
                $RankingsArray[0][$runcount] == "Points" or
                $RankingsArray[0][$runcount] == "Average" or
                $RankingsArray[0][$runcount] == "Floor" or
                $RankingsArray[0][$runcount] == "Ceiling"){

                $run{$runcount} == "yes";
                $runcount = $runcount + 1;
            }
        }
```

what i want to do is set the $run0 variable to "yes" if it satisfies any of those conditions. then set the $run1 variable to "yes" if it satisfies any of those conditions. then set the $run2 variable etc etc.

can i reference and set variables like this? if so what is the correct syntax as `$run{$runcount} == "yes";` is not working

Comment: `==` is not an assignment. "Can I" - try it out. But why would you do it like this and not just use an array?

Comment: Also, why?  Just use an array `$run[$runcount] = "yes";`

Comment: by can i meant is it possible to define variables in the manner that i am suggesting. i have tried it out and '$run{$runcount} == "yes";' was not working as it makes the browser appear to hang. That is why i was asking about the correct syntax to use if this manner is possible. I can't use an array (at least i dont think i can) because the user is uploading a CSV that may be reordered and i only want to look at certain rows based on the header value. the == assignment operator was an error on my part.

Comment: Also, if any iteration doesn't evaluate to true then you will get an endless loop because `$runcount` won't ever change.

Comment: you are right - this is just a poor design. i'm changing this to an array on second thought. I'm self learning php and haven't quite learned best practice yet. thank you for your time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the correct way is

```
 ${'run'.$runcount} = "yes";
```

Comment: And you missed the `=`